# Making "*" and space the same size

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am preparing a little project for people being new to developing. It includes some HTML stuff, where they should make some forms like rectangles or triangles with Javascript. The forms are supposed to be "drawn" by "*". Since I am going to introduce the `&nbsp;` element and some simple for and if-constructs, I want them to create a rectangle that looks like this:

```
* * * * 
 * * * 
* * * *
 * * * 
* * * *
```

in a different size.

I can imagine a code looking like this:

```js
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (j % 2 == 1) {
      if (i % 2 == 1) {
        document.write("*");
      } else {
        document.write("&nbsp;");
      }
    } else {
      if (i % 2 != 1) {
        document.write("*");
      } else {
        document.write("&nbsp;");
      }
    }
  }
  document.write("<br/>");
}
```

Since I've just tried it out, I was wondering, that in HTML the "*" and the space does not have the same size. Now I am looking for the command to make it the same size (since I know there is one), but I can't find it.

Comment: Using the `pre` tag is probably quickest and easiest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not javascript issue at all.

You have to use `monospace` fonts. Basically this group of fonts has the same pixel width for every character.

Read more about here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (j % 2 == 1) {
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    document.write("*");
                } else {
                    document.write("<span class='space'></span>");
                }
            } else {
                if (i % 2 != 1) {
                    document.write("*");
                } else {
                    document.write("<span class='space'></span>");
                }
            }
        }
        document.write("<br/>");}
```

```css
.space {
margin-left: 10px; // change this as you require
}
```